# What happens to Service while android wear is charging?

Tags: java, android, android-service, wear-os

I have an `Activity` running on my moto 360, this Activity starts a `Service` once a `Button` is pressed. The Service runs just fine, but... Once I put my watch in the charger, my app crashes, giving the following message:

```
attempt to invoke virtual method 'service.getAcceleration()' on a null object reference.
```

Thing is, both the Activity and the Service works just fine on "normal usage". But once I place my moto 360 on the charging pad, with the Activity visible, I get an "instacrash" with a message similar to that one above.

**P.S.:** My service is started and bound, the reference is held by the `service` variable, and I read data from it every `N` millis using a `Handler`.

**EDIT:** full stack below.

```
01-12 01:13:16.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19078): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-12 01:13:16.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19078): Process: net.mauker.home_ecare, PID: 19078
01-12 01:13:16.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19078): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'double net.mauker.home_ecare.services.AccWatchdogInterface.getAcceleration()' on a null object reference
01-12 01:13:16.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19078):    at net.mauker.home_ecare.activity.MainActivity.updateData(MainActivity.java:102)
01-12 01:13:16.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19078):    at net.mauker.home_ecare.activity.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:22)
01-12 01:13:16.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19078):    at net.mauker.home_ecare.activity.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:39)
01-12 01:13:16.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19078):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
01-12 01:13:16.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19078):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-12 01:13:16.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19078):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
01-12 01:13:16.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19078):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
01-12 01:13:16.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19078):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-12 01:13:16.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19078):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
01-12 01:13:16.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19078):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
01-12 01:13:16.693: E/AndroidRuntime(19078):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

And the error line:

```
double acc = service.getAcceleration();
```

And I'm getting the `Service` binder here:

```
private AccWatchdogInterface service;

//...

@Override
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
    this.service = ((AccWatchdogBinder) service).getService();
    mHandler.post(runnable);
}
```

---

I can make this question even a bit more generic. What happens on a Wear Activity lifecycle once I plug the charger?

**EDIT:** The `Service` is getting killed in the exact moment that I put the wear into the charger. Still don't know why. If I don't do that it doesn't get killed anytime soon.

I did check for `null` and it stopped the crashing. But my `Service` was not supposed to get killed, and I want to know why it happens on the charger (lifecycle issues?).

Comment: Can you provide the full stack?

Comment: Done, full stack trace on the question, along with some code.

Comment: your service can be killed by the system at any moment (and depending on how it was set up, it may be restarted by system again) so when it is killed, do you have safeguards against trying to use it in your app? I don't see your source so I am not sure what is being done in your app.

Comment: Yes, and it's getting killed in the exact moment that I put the wear into the charger. Still don't know why. If I don't do that it doesn't get killed anytime soon. I did check for `null` and it stopped the crashing. But my Service was not supposed to get killed, and I want to know why it happens on the charger.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "my service was not supposed to be killed"; any background service can be killed by the framework at any time; if the service is set up appropriately, then framework will restart the service when it has enough resources, etc. In other words, you should not program based on the assumption that your service is not going to be killed. Even if it is not killed when you connect it to a charger, it may be killed at some other time and you'll run into the exact same scenario.

Comment: No, you didn't get what I meant. I know about the lifecycle, memory management and so on. But tell me, why the service of my running and active app ONLY kills the Service in the exact moment that I plug the charger? It's not a memory issue for sure, otherwise the (bound) Service would likely be killed before I plug the charger.

Comment: Analyzing why your service was killed at that moment is not an easy task; there is nothing special in the framework that says when you start charging, kill these services. My point here is that it really doesn't matter why it was killed at that exact moment (except as an academic topic) as far as your program is concerned; you need to consider (and adapt accordingly) to the possibility of your service being killed by the framework at any moment.